# Azure Storage and Cache from nearest edge server

Tags: azure, caching, architecture, azure-blob-storage, azure-redis-cache

My application needs to speed up content delivery(basically large files).
I am planning to Data lakes storage structure for storing my files and while downloading
the files from data lake file should be cached so that the next time when the same request comes it picks it up from the cache.

Here the steps how it should be done

1. User requests a file from U.S.A. Request is routed to the closest edge server based on geographical location.
2. If file is cached in edge then serve from edge otherwise get it from data lake storage and cache it in edge.
3. Additional users (like India user) may then request the same file and should be redirected to the nearest edge.

Please help me to find out which might be the best way in Azure to cache big files and retrieve based on location so that latency is less.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Azure CDN. Depending on your use case, this might work.

You can get better performance and user experience for end users, especially when using applications where multiple round-trips are required to load content. This can help with in high scale scenarios with better handling of spiky load and serving requests/ content from edge servers.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-overview/

Comment: Hi Dinesh...  Yes we had 1.Azure CDN and 2.RedisCache in our mind.So need help on which might better serve our purpose. Thanks